# Not getting Status Code in Custom Apache Log

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to use Custom Log for my Apache servers which are acting as proxy servers.

I am using the following configuration:

```
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combinedvhost

ErrorLog logs/sales_com_error_log
CustomLog logs/sales_com_access_log combinedvhost
```

But the log which is written to log file is as followed:

```
 sales.com 117.98.194.77 - - [17/Nov/2017:02:33:29 -0500] "POST /rest/analytics/1.0/publish/bulk HTTP/1.1" 263961 "https://sales.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
```

With the output it is clear that **%>s** and **%D** are not being added  to log file.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious is: did you restart?

The second is that I *think* that the [`LogFormat`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) directive won't change existing nicknames. So if the *"combinedvhost"* nickname is already defined elsewhere changing the recorded fields with a second `LogFormat <other-options> combinedvhost` entry *might* not take effect.
Could you try giving your custom LogFormat a custom nickname:

```
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" mycombinedvhost

CustomLog logs/sales_com_access_log mycombinedvhost
```

and then restart?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply... but still no luck..I restarted it. And tried changing to other name too

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved with the following arrangement of switches.

```
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %b %D" combinedvhost
```

Here %b and %D are moved to last.

Thanks